# Detecting HTML5 data attribute in Modernizr

Tags: html, modernizr, feature-detection, custom-data-attribute

How do I detect if the browser supports HTML5 `data` attribute using Modernizr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test whether an element has the property `dataset`.

```
Modernizr.addTest('data', function () {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    return !!elem.dataset;
});
```

Comment: `!!` just ensures that the value returned is either `true` or `false`, rather than, say, `undefined` which evaluates to `false` or `function(){/* code */}`, which evaluates to `true` when treated as a boolean.

Comment: Yep. In an unsupporting browser elem.dataset = undefined. !undefined = true. !true = false. So !!elem.dataset returns false in an unsupported browser. In a supported one it returns a DOMStringMap, which is a not a falsy value. ! that = false, !false = true.

Comment: @Rich How do you put this into use in `if` statement? In other words I want to perform an action if this is true and another if it is false. Do you do that inside or outside the `.addTest` function?

Comment: Run that first, then it will make the variable Modernizr.data, which is a boolean. It also adds the class "data" to the html element, for CSS, if needed.